# How to disable scrollbar on Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, windows-phone-7, mobile

I need to disable scrollbars if a user is on my site with a mobile device.
I found this solution on this forum:

```
$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault();})
```

It works on android, but it doesn't seem to work on Windows Phone. Should I do something else for Windows Phone devices?

Comment: Where are the scrollbars in question? just the main one for the site scrolling down the body?

Comment: The main scrollbars. For instance, i made a page with 3000px of height, so the page  it's much higher than the browsers of mobile devices. I dont' want to allow users to scroll the page.

Comment: Have you tried just css?  `$('html, body').css({width: '100%', height: '100%', overflow: 'hidden'})`

Comment: yes. both seems not working on windows phone